# Pass values to controller and come back to calling view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I've got a button for which I dynamically create target URI with jquery. Controller action will do some update on database and I want it to display view that call it in the first place. This view can differ. How do you deal with such a scenario?

The idea is that you click on label, provide translation for it, click save and you can see you translation on your current page. I made it work with single page just fine but scaling it up is a problem.

I know I can pass around current page URI and then parse it 'by hand' and put it in RedirectToAction but is there cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a PUT and just update the label on the current page on Success.

Don't wrap the ajax call in a while loop. the success function is only called if the server returns a success (without checking the documentation I assume it is fired on some http 200 status or other)

If you just want to reload on success I guess the below would do it.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: /my/url/for/adding/a/translation,
  data: theTranslation,
  success: function() {window.location.reload(true);}
});
```

Comment: but how do you make sure it was successful? I tried this but no luck `code $("a[class='save']").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        updateSuccessful = false;
        while (!updateSuccessful) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: $(this).attr('href'),
                success: updateSuccessful = true
            });
        }
        window.location.reload(true);
    });`

Comment: Well this updated answer seems to work. Before somehow page would refresh but update would not happen. Am I right that the problem was caused by page reload before actual ajax call was finished?

Comment: This is can of worms. Characters I'm trying to use are not supported but I guess its a problem that I can find answer somewhere else on the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jquery.put to call your action.

This will not result in a redirect, instead jou can have a client side function that handles the return from the controller and updates the page DOM client side directly.

Comment: shouldn't really use jquery.get for a URL that will change a resource. it sounds like this is creation so should use PUT